# Using Em's why does the browser calculate Padding, Margin, line-height wrong?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm starting a new project and thought i would give em's ago but I have noticed that when using em's for Padding, Margin, line-height etc(anything but fonts) The browsers doesn't calculate them properly.

Example:

I was using Firebug to quickly position elements around using pixels then I translated them in my stylesheet using the formula pixel size / base font. so 25px / 16px = 1.5625

When I refreshed my browser the element was a few pixels out and it seems I have to round it up or down or in one case it was really out!

Is it just me or has anyone else noticed or have a solution?

Answer: my base font was wrong!!

Comment: tell a font-size of body tag?

Comment: Post some code and describe a specific problem (expected result vs. actual result – specify concretely). Your example is vague and refers to px, not em.

Comment: Ok next time it happens i will post it.

Answer (score 1):

> I translated them in my stylesheet using the formula pixel size / base
>   font. so 25px / 16px

If you are using ems, it's best to leave pixels behind. The 16px base font idea is not reliable. It's just more of a general guide, as you don't know what the user's real base font (system font) size is, because they can set it to anything (although most people probably don't touch it).

And when you are dealing in % of pixels, each browser has its own way of dealing with that (such as rounding up or down) and you have to let the browser do its thing. On the web, all is relative, and as long as you have the elements of the page all set in nice proportions to each other, the design should work nicely at any zoom level or viewport width.

Comment: The font is 100% on the body which works out at 16px is users dont touch there font settings.

Comment: Not necessarily. It's not reliable, just a guide.

Answer (score -2):

EM's get compounded when nested in child elements. For example, if you use body font-size: is 16px, and then in a header you have 1.1em, then inside that header you have  menu item and you set it to 1em, it will equal to the parent at 1.1em(most likely around 18px).

The way around this is to use REM, which stands for the "root" EM. This keep your sizes from being compounded when nested. However, there is limited support for this on various browsers. To work around that, you use a PX fallback. In the fallback, any browser will use the last acceptable rule. If it doesn't understand the rule(REM), it ignores it, thus using the PX.

```
header {
   font-size: 18px;
   font-size: 1.1rem;
}
nav {
   font-size: 16px;
   font-size: 1rem;
}
```

Finally, it's important to understand that EM/REM's are like PERCENTAGES, not fixed pixels.

Comment: `rem` is unnecessary when you just use `em` with due notice of its meaning, and using pixels as “fallback” breaks the idea. Moreover, the CSS code presented is invalid.

Comment: In addition, EMs and REMs are not percentages. And pixels aren't fixed: sometimes a pixel is a device pixel, sometimes not.

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela You use REM instead of EM. YOu need a PX fallback if you use REM because of limited browser support. Just look at how Wordpress does this the same way. Em's and REM's are like percentages. That are scalable based on document size. How is that not a percentage? Please look at: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem